# Mail subject and content must change as per Order status : Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

Anyone has done or know.

How we can update/change email subject and email template according to order status.

each and every status has different email subject line and different comment according to status.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have set an email Template according to Order status.

now, we can set every order status has different email template.

for that, we have over right below model

```
\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\OrderCommentIdentity
```

In this model, there is `getTemplateId` function where we can set email template id whatever you want to set.

Please review the below image for more details

[image]

Comment: did u do it vai any module

Comment: No, i have did custom development for same